# In App billing v5 Wrong pricing in Android

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I'm using InAppbilling v5 in Android to retrieve the price of the Items, everything is working correctly, however when "Google" review my app they rejected because I'm not following the Subscription guidelines. In my test the price is retrived correctly but for in the Screenshots of Google there is a "Free", formatted price string instead $9.00 so I'm not sure how to fix this issue because apparently only happens when Google review my app. I'm using the following code to retrieve the products

```kotlin
   billingClient.queryProductDetails(
                        subscriptions.toQueryProduct(ProductType.SUBS)
                    ).productDetailsList
```

Then I'm retrieving the offer details like this:

```kotlin
val price = productDetails.subscriptionOfferDetails
                                ?.firstOrNull()
                                ?.pricingPhases?.pricingPhaseList
                                ?.firstOrNull()
                                ?.formattedPrice ?: ""
```

In my devices and emulator works correctly displaying the correct price, however for google it display "free" as `formattedPrice` How I can solve this?
In my Subscriptions in the Play Store console I have only one price/base offer with a 7 days free trial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, the problem was that in the new version v5 if the user never had any subscription there will be 2 phases, the "free" trial which price is free and the subscription price after trial, I tested with my user and since I already had any subscription the "free" was not available, but for new users that never had any subscription there was a free opion. for now in my code I'm filtering the free with this code

```kotlin
 // there can be several pricingPhases and trial can be "free"
                            val formattedPrice = offerDetails?.pricingPhases
                                ?.pricingPhaseList
                                ?.firstOrNull { it.priceAmountMicros > 0 }
                                ?.formattedPrice
```

using `it.priceAmountMicros > 0` will filter any item that is not "free" or has a price

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I too was wondering in which circumstances can you have multiple pricing phase.